# distance from my current location to another location

Tags: iphone

Hey I am trying to get distance from my current location to another location. But while trying to do so I have been stuck for last 5 hrs. Heres what I am doing and am unable to figure why am I getting an error here:

```
CLLocation *myloc=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

CLLocationDistance dince = [myloc distanceFromLocation:location];
```

I have searched it all over the net and everyone is using the same lines, but to me it says incompatible type for argument. Can someone please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Please post the exact error, tell us which line is producing it, and show us the definition of `location`.

Comment: Hi,
location is of the type CLLocationCordinate2D. And so I found that it was the buggy line. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> location is of the type CLLocationCordinate2D.

For the benefit of future readers, I'll point out that the problem was that `-distanceFromLocation:` expects its parameter to be a `CLLocation*`, not a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be a * in the second line? Like this? -

```
CLLocationDistance *dince = [myloc distanceFromLocation:location];
```

Comment: nope.. thats not working.. in this line the error is incompatible type for argument1

Comment: No, CLLocationDistance is just a double, and -distanceFromLocation: returns CLLocationDistance, not CLLocationDistance*.

Comment: So, what am I ding wrong here? What should I do to correct it?